# textarea placeholder color not changing in firefox

Tags: html, css, webkit

i have this form:

```css
:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="#" method="post">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 padding-2">
        <textarea class=" form-control textArea" rows="7" placeholder="Comments/Requests" name="textarea" id="textarea" required="required"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  placeholder not changing in textarea i tried this css tricks:
```

the body have a blue background color and the placeholder should be white, it is showing gray...any help? i am new to web development... thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-html5-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css/2610741#2610741

Answer (score 1):

[From the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-placeholder):

> Non-standard
>  
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

and

> Obsolete
>   This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.

and

> Note: Firefox 51 replaced this feature with the standard `:placeholder-shown` pseudo-class.